# Testing variable equality in twig

Tags: php, templates, twig

In [twig](http://www.twig-project.org/), is there an easy way to test the equality of 2 variables?

`{% if var1 = var2 %}` isn't valid, `{% if var1 is sameas(var2) %}` only works if both are a strings...

(from docs) "sameas checks if a variable points to the same memory address than another variable", like thats useful.

So the only way I've found of comparing integers is to convert them both to strings:
`{% if var1|lower is sameas(var2|lower) %}`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As far as I'm aware Twig supports all of the standard logical operators `==, !=, <, >, >=, and <=.` Also, your first example `{% if var1 = var2 %}` does not check for equality, it assigns `var2` to `var1`, you might want to change it to the comparison operator `==`.

The Twig `sameas` built in test, is essentially a strict type comparison operator `===`, hence why they both need to be strings in your example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comparing value which have a numeric value you can use:

```
{% if (psong.songid) ==(song.id) %}
```